# Wordpress 404 error file path is incorrect

Tags: wordpress

i am getting errors of file. When i look into console there path is generating as

```
http://test.astech-us.com/tupperco/tupperco/tupperco/wp-content/plugins/revslider/admin/assets/css/tipsy.css?ver=5.2.5
```

Project name is coming three times. i had updated plugins still getting this error files are not loading

Please guide 
Thanks

Comment: tuperco is project name its coming three time that's why path is incorrect

Answer (score -1):

> `/tupperco/tupperco/tupperco/` is your problem